# Search via amule-js from terminal using Node.js to retrieve ED2Ks or hash of files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I read [here](https://github.com/tbo47/amule-js)

> Amule-js is a typescript and/or javascript (ES6) library to communicate with amule.

I take a look inside and I find this

`search`: initiates a search on the server.
`fetchSearch`: fetches the search results
`getDownloads, download, getSharedFiles`: functions related to downloading and obtaining information about shared files.

I want to perform a search and fetch ed2k or hash of files from terminale: is a good way to use node.js with something like this?

`node main.js`

```
const amuleCli = new AMuleCli();  // Create an instance of AMuleCli

// Connection to the server and authentication
amuleCli.connect()
  .then(() => {
    // Perform a search
    return amuleCli.search('tuo_termine_di_ricerca');
  })
  .then(results => {
    // Process the search results
    results.forEach(result => {
      console.log(`Nome del file: ${result.partfile_name}`);
      console.log(`EDK2: ${result.partfile_hash}`);
      console.log('---');
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(`Errore: ${error}`);
  });
```